# How to implement background-position-x in tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to make my background image responsive using tailwind. Can't find background-position-x in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, TailwindCSS doesn't have a utility for this. Except for adding it as a utility either by a [plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins) or in [CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer), if you're using the JIT Mode, the shortest way to do this is adding it as an [arbitrary property](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties).

For example adding this: `[background-position-x:-100px]` will generate:

```
.\[background-position-x\:-100px\] {
  background-position-x: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply use the `bg-center` `bg-bottom`... `bg-left-bottom` classes, as explained [here](https://www.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-position).

If you need more flexibility, you can use TailwindCSS with PostCSS, and edit `theme.backgroundPosition` in your `tailwind.config.js`. You can then add more complex rules there.

Comment: I think what is asked might be something along the lines of `background-position: center 100px`. So it is horizontally centered, but vertically has a 'gap' of 100px. FYI: no idea how to do this in tailwind.

Comment: Looks like this could be done with [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values). For example, `background-position: center 100px` would look like `bg-[center_100px]` (not tested but looks correct going off of the syntax in the docs)